# stop submission if form is not validated

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a form and I have a "cancel" and submit button. when user submits the form, if required fields are not filled, I want to alert("error") and stop the form to be submitted.

here is my simple jquery code but when user click ok button on alert box, it continues to submit.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=btn_reddet.ClientID %>').click(function (event) {
        alert("Error!");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

how can I make it stop submitting after alert?

Comment: It seems you've got the answer, although I would suggest using the built in .net validators.  They allow easy client and server side validation.  Which should always be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `.click`, you can use `.submit`, You just need to return false to stop form submission

```
$('#formID').on('submit',function (event) {
        alert("Error!");
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$('form').submit()` event instead of `$('submit_button').click()`. Then `return false` if validation fails:

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(e) {
    var validated = true; 
    // some validation code which sets 'validated = false' if it fails
    return validated;
});
```

Comment: Why is `preventDefault` different than `return false` in this case?

Comment: In this case, I can simply `return validated` and skip testing whether `validated` is true or false.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But why will that work if `event.preventDefault()` doesn't?

Comment: Because you were preventing the click event, but the submit event was also triggered and was continuing on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Then I believe that also needs to be followed by

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Otherwise you can just use return false.

Comment: Why would `stopPropagation()` help?

Comment: Oh doesn't e.preventDefault() prevent the default event from occuring and e.stopPropagation() prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree while return false effectively does both?

Comment: `e.preventDefault() prevent the default event from occuring and e.stopPropagation() prevents the event from bubbling up` - if the event never occurs, why would it bubble up?

Comment: e.preventDefault() does not prevent other handlers from executing.

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault() and return false do not work the same, the differences exist when something goes wrong (read: error) and whether or not event.preventDefault() has already executed or not, here is an example of when it matters and why return false does not always work:

```
$('a').click( function(e){
    $(this).css("background", "green");
    err();  // err is not defined, so JavaScript will throw error, and the browser will ignore rest of the code (return false;). The browser will perform the default action.
    return false;
});
$('a').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("background", "green");
    err();  // err is not defined, so JavaScript will throw error, and the browser will ignore rest of the code. We already called event.preventDefault() so the browser will not perform default action.
});
```